# Apache Camel-2.22.1 Unable to evaluate dynamic date expression in output directory

Tags: java, apache-camel, fuseesb

I am trying to send file to an output location to a directory with `todate` as suffix as given in the format `file:D:/out-${date:now:yyyyMMdd}`.

But I am getting exception.

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:>

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Recipient List (http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) to dynamically build the to uri. If you are using DSL to build your route, it would look something like this:

```
from("file://C:/in")
    .recipientList(simple("file:D:/out-${date:now:yyyyMMdd}"));
```